# How to set release limit while using php-deployer?

Tags: php, laravel, php-deployer

I am using PHP deployer 6.6.0 to deploy Laravel based websites.

Every time I deploy it creates a new release. Currently, I have more than 10 releases and it's eating up a lot of disk space.

I don't want to keep more than the last 3 releases and need the older releases to automatically roll over.

How can I specify the maximum number of releases to be kept?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option you want is called `keep_releases`. See the docs [here](https://deployer.org/docs/6.x/configuration#keep_releases).

(Link points to V6 docs, since currently V7 docs fail to mention this setting. Although I see it mentioned [on this upgrade guide](https://deployer.org/docs/7.x/UPGRADE), so I assume it still works).

By default, deployer keeps only 5 releases, so if you have more than 10 it means you changed the default configuration.

You'll probably have `set('keep_releases', -1);` in your configuration. Change it, so it stores only a reasonable number of releases, or delete the line directly and it will only keep 5 releases around.

```php
set('keep_releases', 3); // e.g. for a maximum of 3 releases
```

Comment: Please observe that the release folders in excess will be deleted immediately.

Comment: How would I set this in the YAML syntax? The documentation on it isn't great.

Comment: @HashimAziz Documentation for v7 is less complete than for v6, apparently. But [here](https://deployer.org/docs/7.x/UPGRADE) you can find an example of how to use this option on a YAML configuration.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using that, and it's worth noting that as of v7 at least the default value for `keep_releases` is 10.